# Check for specific element in a list in Drools using dsl,dslr

Tags: drools, dsl

I just started using drools workbench 6.5.0

I have two classes

```
class Client{
    String name;
    String age;
    List<Products> products; 
}

class Product {
    String code;
    String description;
}
```

There is a way can i fire rules that matches an element in the list of products of determined client using dsl and dslr?

i used the following dsl

```
[keyword][]regla=rule
[keyword][]cuando=when
[keyword][]entonces=then
[keyword][]fin=end

[when][]es menor o igual que=<=
[when][]es menor que=<
[when][]es mayor o igual que=>=
[when][]es mayor que=>
[when][]es igual que===
[when][]igual===
[when][]- {campo:\w*} {operador} {valor:\d*}={campo} {operador} {valor} 

[when][]Hay un cliente =$c : Client($products: products)
[when][]nombre = name
[when][]edad = age
[when][]codigo = code
[when][]Hay producto = $p : Product() from $products
```

and the following condition

```
cuando 
        Hay un cliente
            - edad es mayor o igual que 12
            - nombre igual "John"
        Hay producto
            - codigo es igual que  "4"
```

Comment: Sure there is. Can you show how you attempted to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i have put the code of my attemp

Comment: This is the part of the documentation which talks about how to add a constraint to a fact using the DSLR: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.31.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_adding_constraints_to_facts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me. The test below prints correct client name which has respective product code.

**test**

```
@DroolsSession(resources = { "classpath:/test.rdslr", "classpath:/business.dsl" })
public class PlaygroundTest {

    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        drools.insertAndFire(new Client("client1", 40, asList(new Product("1", "product 1"), new Product("2", "product 2"))));
        drools.insertAndFire(new Client("John", 50, asList(new Product("3", "product 3"), new Product("4", "product 4"))));
    }
}
```

**rule**

```
regla X
cuando 
    Hay un cliente
        - edad es mayor o igual que 12
        - nombre igual "John"
    Hay producto
        - codigo es igual que  "4"
entonces
    print client name
fin
```

**dsl**

```
[keyword][]regla=rule
[keyword][]cuando=when
[keyword][]entonces=then
[keyword][]fin=end

[when][]es menor o igual que=<=
[when][]es menor que=<
[when][]es mayor o igual que=>=
[when][]es mayor que=>
[when][]es igual que===
[when][]igual===
[when][]- {campo:\w*} {operador} {valor:\d*}={campo} {operador} {valor} 

[when][]Hay un cliente =$c : Client($products: products)
[when][]nombre = name
[when][]edad = age
[when][]codigo = code
[when][]Hay producto = $p : Product() from $products

[then]print client name = System.out.println($c.name);
```

**model**

```
public class Client {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public List<Product> products;

    public Client(String name, int age, List<Product> products) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.products = products;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}

public class Product {
    public String code;
    public String description;

    public Product(String code, String description) {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**test output**

```
00:00:00 --> inserted: Client[name=client1,age=40,products=[org.droolsassert.Product@4fbdc0f0, org.droolsassert.Product@2ad3a1bb]]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 --> inserted: Client[name=John,age=50,products=[org.droolsassert.Product@71e9a896, org.droolsassert.Product@6b9267b]]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 <-- 'X' has been activated by the tuple [Client, Product]
John
```

After inserting first client no rules got triggered, after inserting John rule was triggered and client name printed.

What unexpected result did you get?

Comment: My issue was 'problem expanding variable' when i used validate in drools workbench, even with test case i got the same problem, the same with kie client multiple times, but today the issue hasn't show anymore.
I think it was a kie server issue.
Thanks anyway.